# Display RTF with DocumentViewer

Tags: wpf, rtf, documentviewer

I need to display a RTF document in my WPF Application. I think DocumentViewer is the best choice because of search box and toolbar with print, zoom and so on. The problem is that I don't realize how to convert RTF format to FixedDocument. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623054/how-can-we-show-rtf-or-doc-as-flowdocument-in-wpf

Comment: Thanks. That works for FlowDocument, but I need FixedDocument